# How do you say that some time had elapsed?

Tags: phrase-request

I want to express simply that some time had elapsed. Is the following correct?

> It was passed 10 minutes.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: You can say 'it has been 10 minutes since I got here' which means '10 minutes have passed since I came here.'

Comment: Just forget the *"of time"* part (if they "elapsed", they can't be [units of angular measurement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute_of_arc). So *"ten minutes had elapsed"* is all you need. Or *"passed"*, if you want a more common verb.

Comment: This question is edited too much and not reflect original - I want to delete it :)

Comment: I don't understand what this question is asking now, and I'm totally bewildered by all the edits made. The only interesting thing I can see here is: *Why can't we use the 'dummy it' of "It rained yesterday", or "It was ten minutes later when [blah blah]" in something more like (OP's postulated?) construction "It passed ten minutes"*? But there's no evidence that's what's being asked, so I think the question is Too Localised (whatever the question actually is! :)

Comment: Not know purpose of all edits. Changes changed the question - whatever the answer still answers. You could not understand this question since you are *native speaker* for me it is not clear that "ten minutes have passing/gone* In Polish time is passing but not going ... not want use Polishenglish want to use English.

Comment: @ Chameleon: In English, time usually *passes*, or *goes **by***. We normally say *"10 minutes passed"*, or *"10 minutes went by"* (where *went* is the past tense of *to go*). You'll sometimes see *by* with *to pass*, and sometimes it *won't* be there with *to go*, but those are less common versions. Let me know if that's what you're asking about. Note that the current *"It was passed 10 minutes"* in your text isn't a valid English sentence, but it would probably be understood as meaning *"It was 10 minutes **later**"* (than some earlier time which you had just been talking about).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for help now it become clear for me now - hints with *tenses* are very useful since Polish are expressing it differently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *Ten minutes have passed.*

is the grammatically correct form. Another way to say it is:

> *Ten minutes have gone by.*

There are undoubtedly other ways of noting the passage of a specific number of minutes, but these are the two that come immediately to my mind.

To use the past tenses, you can say:

> Ten minutes passed.  [simple past]
>   Ten minutes had passed.  [past perfect]

Which form you choose depends on context. Your sentence has no context.

Comment: Is past tense forms is invalid?

Comment: The present perfect tense is the one normally used in these cases. In some cases, British English uses the present perfect when American English would use the past tense, but I think this is one of those cases where both would use the present perfect.

Comment: @Chameleon: The past tense form would be: "ten minutes passed [before my bus arrived]", or "it took ten minutes for my bus to arrive".